# How to call a function from case in shell script?

Tags: bash, scripts

Hi all I am trying to run a shell script with case statement

```
opt=$1
case $opt
in
    u) function1 ;;
    g) function2 ;;
    *) exit ;;
esac

function1()
{
    xyz commands
}

funciton2t()
{
    xyz commands
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
function1: command not found
```

Comment: after having the functions above the case it worked, but if I give the two options at a time only the first option is working!!!

Comment: @kashyap `case` doesn't loop. You should use `getopt` or `getopts` for processing options. Or maybe you want to loop through arguments with `for arg; do case ... ; esac; done`

Answer (score 7):

When you are calling a function, it should be defined and known, when you are calling the `function1` at this like:

```
u) function1 ;;
```

Interpreter has no idea where this function is, because it has not seen it yet; so put your functions above the `case` sentence.

That would fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

@kashyap (and others). It is unclear to me whether you have enough response to fix your issue?
I have modified your code slightly to really see what is taking place:

```
function1()
{
    echo "I am function 1"
}

function2()
{
    echo "I am function 2"
}

opt=$1
case $opt
in
    u) function1 ;;
    g) function2 ;;
    *) echo "Nothing to do"
       exit ;;
esac
```

I named the file **dummyFunc**, gave it x-bits and these are the results.

```
$ ./dummyFunc u
I am function 1
$ ./dummyFunc g
I am function 2
$ ./dummyFunc 
Nothing to do
$
```

I hope this helps  **kashyap** ?
If not, show us how your script now looks like and add the output it generates.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 syntax errors:
 the i before the t and a t behind the 2:

```
funciton2t()
{
xyz commands
}
```

Comment: That's not a syntax error, just a typo.

Comment: They're technically different. A syntax error gives exit code 2. A command not found error (caused by a typo) gives exit code 127.

Comment: That's not why function 1 is throwing an error is it?

Comment: @wjandrea: sorry mate, I thought you were kidding, as the misspelling was so obvious the cause. Also, it was past midnight, so I wasn't too clear anymore. But indeed, you are right. Types and syntax errors are completely different things.

Comment: @Zanna: what error are you referring to?

Comment: `function1: command not found`

Comment: ah, I think that was the old situation, when the functions were not above the regular code.

Comment: @kashyap:  do you need more help ?